# Setup boto3 to connect to custom host, similar to s3cmd

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3, s3cmd

With s3cmd I am able to connect to a bucket with the following config file:

```
[default]
access_key = <VARIABLE>
secret_key = <VARIABLE>
host_base = <VARIABLE>
host_bucket = <VARIABLE>
use_https = True
```

I'd rather build a Python script to connect to a S3 bucket instead of s3cmd and am looking at boto3 right now. However I cannot find a way to define the `host_bucket` variable. I am currently using the following code:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=<VARIABLE>,
    aws_secret_access_key=<VARIABLE>,
    endpoint_url=<VARIABLE>
)

for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    print(bucket, bucket.name)
```

This returns zero.

Comment: I want to do exactly this. At the moment I'm using `subprocess.Popen` to run `s3cmd`, which seems unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

With your CMD use `aws configure` then you need to fill in the infos.

after in your code use

```
import boto3
 
# Let's use Amazon S3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
```

and something like this:

```
for obj in s3.Bucket("mybucket"):
    print(obj.key)
```

see the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/quickstart.html#installation)